# Editing Combobox item in Datagridview in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I have a `Datagridview` in Winform. One of the column is a `Combobox`. Is it possible to set the property such that user can enter apart from being able to select the entries from the dropdown list.

I was able to do it on a `Combobox` item with a following changes from the properties window:

```
AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
DropDownStyle : Dropdown;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this may Help :-

```
private void DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    if (DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == yourComboBoxColum)
    {
        ComboBox combo = e.Control as ComboBox;

        if (combo == null)
            return;

        combo.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, It did make the combox cell editable. However, since I have setup the Datagridview in Virtual mode, I am not able to push the new value to the underlying class object. It always revert back to the previous value. Any idea why it might be happening?

Comment: Cant help you with that, Ive not used virtual mode.